# Issue with recursive function and finding all possible routes

Tags: c++, function, recursion

I'm trying to print out all possible paths in a subway system which has stations from A to L. In other words the objective is to find how many possible routes a person could take to get through a subway system without going over a track more than once.  I know there are 640 possible paths since I wrote this program using an adjacency matrix in C earlier. Now I'm trying to write the same program except using classes in C++ without the use of an adjacency matrix.

The problem I'm having is that I can't seem to properly implement my recursive function, SearchRoute, as I need to print the path, flag the path, and then unflag the path again to allow for backtracking. When I print out the final result I only get a track from A to B and that obviously means something is clearly wrong.

This is what I believe the problem is: I know that in my SubwaySystem::SearchRoute function I use an if and else statement which clearly does NOT allow my recursive function to be called but I tried putting another if statement instead of the else but I'm not quite sure what the condition would be.

```
void SubwaySystem::SearchRoute(int Current_Station_ID)
{
    while(Current_Station_ID < 33)
    {
        cout << "In while loop\n";
        // \\ Checking progress
        if(Current_Station_ID == 0)  //Find a successful route to Station L
        {
            count_routes++; //Add 1 into the variable “count_routes”
            cout << "In if statement\n";
            // \\Checking progress
            cout << count_routes << " " << my_track[Current_Station_ID] << endl; //Print out this route
            return;
        }
        else //Get into recursive Function Body
        {
            for(int i = my_station[Current_Station_ID].track_starting_ID; i < my_station[Current_Station_ID].track_starting_ID + my_station[Current_Station_ID].track_size; i++)
            {
                if(my_track[Current_Station_ID].visited == 0)  //if this track is not visited before
                {
                    cout << "In recursive part of function\n";
                    // \\ Checking progress
                    my_track[Current_Station_ID].visited = 1; //mark this track as visited
                    my_track[Current_Station_ID].node_2 = 1; //mark its corresponding track as visited
                    cout << my_track[Current_Station_ID] << endl; //save this track
                    SearchRoute(Current_Station_ID + 1); //Recursive
                    i--; //Backtrack this track
                    my_track[Current_Station_ID].visited = 0;//mark this track as unvisited
                    my_track[Current_Station_ID].node_2 = 0;//mark its corresponding track as unvisited
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also I tried putting in print statements along the way to track progress throughout the program. My recursive function never gets called for the reasons I specified above (at least that's why I think its not working). And for some reason that I can't figure out why my default and overload track constructors are called several times.

I would appreciate if you could help me figure out the problem areas in my code/ show me the correct way. I'm tired of thinking about this. Thanks in advance.

Here is the rest of the program in a single TU :

```
//Function Declarations
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#ifndef SUBWAY_H
#define SUBWAY_H

class Track
{
public:
    //Default Constructor
    Track();

    //Overload Constructor
    Track(char, char);

    //Destructor
    ~Track();

    //Member variables
    char node_1;
    char node_2;
    bool visited;
};

class Station
{
public:
    //Default Constructor
    Station();

    //Destructor
    ~Station();

    //Overload Constructor
    Station(char, int, int);

    //Member variables
    char station_name;
    int track_starting_ID;
    int track_size;
};

class SubwaySystem
{
public:
    //Default Constructor
    SubwaySystem();

    //Destructor
    ~SubwaySystem();

    //Recursive function
    void SearchRoute(int);

    //Other member functions
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Track& my_track);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Station& my_station);


    //Member variables
    Track my_track[34];
    Station my_station[12];

    int count_routes;
    int Current_Station_ID;

    //String to save found route
};

#endif

// **cpp**

//Function Definitions
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

//#include "subway.h"

using namespace std;

Track::Track()
{
    visited = 0;
    //cout << "Default Track has been called\n";
    //\\ Checking progress
}


Track::~Track()
{
}


Track::Track(char pass_track1, char pass_track2)
{
    node_1 = pass_track1;
    node_2 = pass_track2;
    visited = false;
    //cout << "Overload Track constructor has been called\n";
    // \\ Checking progress
}


Station::Station()
{
}


Station::~Station()
{
}


Station::Station(char pass_station_name, int pass_start, int pass_size)
{
    station_name = pass_station_name;
    track_starting_ID = pass_start;
    track_size = pass_size;
    //cout << "Overload station has been called\n";
    // \\ Checking progress
}


SubwaySystem::SubwaySystem()
{
    //Initialize tracks
    //node_1, node_2
    my_track[0] = Track('a', 'b');
    my_track[1] = Track('b', 'a');
    my_track[2] = Track('b', 'c');
    my_track[3] = Track('b', 'd');
    my_track[4] = Track('b', 'e');
    my_track[5] = Track('b', 'f');
    my_track[6] = Track('c', 'b');
    my_track[7] = Track('c', 'e');
    my_track[8] = Track('d', 'b');
    my_track[9] = Track('d', 'e');
    my_track[10] = Track('e', 'b');
    my_track[11] = Track('e', 'c');
    my_track[12] = Track('e', 'd');
    my_track[13] = Track('e', 'g');
    my_track[14] = Track('e', 'h');
    my_track[15] = Track('f', 'b');
    my_track[16] = Track('f', 'h');
    my_track[17] = Track('g', 'e');
    my_track[18] = Track('g', 'k');
    my_track[19] = Track('h', 'e');
    my_track[20] = Track('h', 'f');
    my_track[21] = Track('h', 'i');
    my_track[22] = Track('h', 'j');
    my_track[23] = Track('h', 'k');
    my_track[24] = Track('i', 'h');
    my_track[25] = Track('i', 'k');
    my_track[26] = Track('j', 'h');
    my_track[27] = Track('j', 'k');
    my_track[28] = Track('k', 'g');
    my_track[29] = Track('k', 'h');
    my_track[30] = Track('k', 'i');
    my_track[31] = Track('k', 'j');
    my_track[32] = Track('k', 'l');
    my_track[33] = Track('l', 'k');
    //Initialize stations
    //station_name, track_starting_ID, track_size
    my_station[0] = Station('a', 0, 1);
    my_station[1] = Station('b', 1, 5);
    my_station[2] = Station('c', 6, 2);
    my_station[3] = Station('d', 8, 2);
    my_station[4] = Station('e', 10, 5);
    my_station[5] = Station('f', 15, 2);
    my_station[6] = Station('g', 17, 2);
    my_station[7] = Station('h', 19, 5);
    my_station[8] = Station('i', 24, 2);
    my_station[9] = Station('j', 26, 2);
    my_station[10] = Station('k', 28, 5);
    my_station[11] = Station('l', 33, 1);
    //Initiaize other members
    count_routes = 0;
    Current_Station_ID = 0;
    //cout << "SubwaySystem constructor called\n";
    // \\ Checking progress
}


SubwaySystem::~SubwaySystem()
{
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Track& my_track)
{
    os << my_track.node_1 << '.' << my_track.node_2;
    return os;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Station& my_station)
{
    os << my_station.station_name << '.' << my_station.track_starting_ID << '.' << my_station.track_size;
    return os;
}



// **main**

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

//#include "subway.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    SubwaySystem Test;
    Test.SearchRoute(0);
}
```

I'm sorry if the "Checking progress" print statements make it harder to read the code.

Comment: Do you know how  annoying its to debug a hundred lines of code ? Please shorten it down, pointing the actually problem

Comment: Sorry. The problem exists within the SearchRoutes function. But I posted the entire code so it may make more sense as to whats happening all together.

Comment: The actual problem is the recursive call to `SearchRoute`, as he said. However, it's embedded in a routine fraught with long lines and vague conditions. I'm not going to read it either

Comment: I edited to make the interesting code more visible and to make the sample self-contained.

Comment: user98289 has a history of defacing questions, probably to hide the fact that this is homework.  
Some discussion can be found at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/11315/18398

Answer (score 0):

Your first condition

```
while(Current_Station_ID < 33)
{
    cout << "In while loop\n";
    // \\ Checking progress
    if(Current_Station_ID == 0)  //Find a successful route to Station L
```

This will **always** be true, because that's what you call in main:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    SubwaySystem Test;
    Test.SearchRoute(0);
}
```

So, you're NEVER going to be in the `else` branch, because the first will always be taken, and it immediately ends (`return`)

Comment: I see. That's what I think is the problem too. The else can never execute. I've been attempting to change the conditions for a while as well as trying to get rid of the else all together and replacing it with another if so I can write another condition. However, I'm not sure what the condition would be then. So I'm slightly lost.

Comment: Just in case, I've made a similar routing solution in modern C++11 [here](https://github.com/sehe/codingames/blob/master/tan_network.cpp) (it's the "TAN Network" training exercise from http://www.codingame.com/cg/#!training). It's more involved and also quite optimized (it's reading the network from a file instead and also knows the latitude/longitude of stations)

Answer (score 0):

With recursive algorithms, your if statement should be true when you reach the final destination.  The else statement is when you are still on your journey.  In this case you have "arrived" when you visit every track.  Continuing on your journey is taken care of by the else statement.  The for loop finds all the "next" stops.

I would extend the recursive call to:

```
void SubwaySystem::SearchRoute(int visited_count, int current_station, string route);
```

If the visited_count is met, print the route. Otherwise, pick the next stations that haven't been visited.
With each recursive call, pick the next station to visit, add 1 to the current visited count, and append the current location to the route string.

Currently you also have a bug if your for loop, my_station only goes up to 11, but Current_Station_ID might be 33.

Comment: If I get rid of the while loop. Won't that cause an infinite loop within the for loop.

Comment: I believe you will eventually set all the nodes visited and quit looping.  But I think I misunderstood the requirement.  I thought you wanted paths from A to L.  I now think you want paths that use all the tracks (once).  For this you have two end conditions: 1) all tracks used, 2) unused tracks unreachable.  The recursive call is to unused, reachable tracks.

Comment: I will add, with respect to the station ID bug, there are 12 stations, 0-11 or rather a-k, but the my_track array enumerates the station transfers.  Each station has a set of possible transfers. Station b, for example, can transfer to a,c,d,e,f and so when you are at station b, you should call SearchRoute with the next station drawn from all of a,c,d,e, and that you haven't already visited.